# Access denied for remote MySql connection

Tags: php, mysql, server, remote-access, bluehost

I've recently built a PHP API (Slim-based) to allow my Android app to access a MySql database remotely.

Everything in the API is tested and ready to go locally, but now that I've uploaded it to the server, I keep getting "Access denied for user 'user'@'box431.bluehost.com' (using password: YES)" error, where 'user' is my correct database username.

I tried deleting that user and creating a new one that has all permissions, to no avail, and the credentials in my config file - database name, user name, password, and host - are also correct. BlueHost is unable to help me any further, so now I turn to SO for help.

Any idea what else might be wrong?? I really only know how to access all these utilities via the cPanel, so any advice doing it through that view (or guidance if hardcoded changes needed) would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: One experiment you can try - add a user with your username and @% as the domain and give it permissions. I have occasionally had problems like this when domains have not been passed as expected. Note this is just an experiment to help nail the problem down, you should remove the user afterwards as it is rather insecure.

Comment: Reformatted a bit, for a better readability.

Comment: Thanks DerGolem, I made some additional formatting edits as well. @Giles, I will see if I can try that as well, thanks - what was the solution when your domains weren't being passed in as they should have?

Comment: I seem to recall I had to carefully scan the incoming connections until I was able to spot exactly who the user and domain were. Later the environment we were using changed so we had multiple domains with shared users so, in mysql, user@% became the norm and we relied on ssh for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the solution was quite simple! My config file had the host name set to the actual IP address, but it should have been "localhost" given that the web service and the database reside on the same server. Duh. Hope this little detail is at least helpful for anyone else out there!

Comment: Ha! - Sorry I should have spotted that, I have had exactly the same trouble on several occasions but I never seem to remember.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to achieve this using cPanel but I think where you're going wrong is the mySQL user hasn't been configured for remote access. You can use the following syntax with the mySQL CLI.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

You'll need to follow that with the following;

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

As Giles pointed out in his comment this is not particularly secure, you'd be better off creating a web service to manipulate the database.

Comment: Thanks, @SuperCabbage, will try this. Silly follow-up question: do I need to SSH in and do something to access the CLI? I don't see any option in the cPanel to access a command line.

Also, the API I referred to is actually my web service that intercedes between any user and the database!

Comment: I can see you answered your own question in the end but yes you would have to SSH in and then use the mySQL prompt (usually along the lines of `mysql -u username -p` then your password at the prompt.

You can read more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html if you're interested